# JNA: Pass Pointer to Structure to SendMessage function of User32.dll as the LPARAM

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I need to perform a simple task : Print out the names of the list view items inside an explorer window. Suppose, I open "C:\Documents and Settings" on my desktop, then what I want to do is that write a java program using JNA to print out all the names of the folders / files within the opened explorer window.

What I have been able to do: Get the handle of the opened explorer window and the handle to the listview inside it.

What I have found out: I need to call the SendMessage function of User32.dll and pass it the handle to the listview found above, along with the message code (which is (0x1000 + 45) for LVM_GETITEMTEXTA), along with the 0 based index number of the list view item whose name I need to get, and, an LPARAM (which is a long value).
This LPARAM will accept a pointer to a structure of type LVITEM.
You can refer the documentation of the message here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761055(v=vs.85).aspx

I have created the structure LVITEM in my interface for User32 as follows:

```
public static class LVITEM extends Structure
    {
        public short mask;
        public int iItem;
        public int iSubItem;
        public short state;
        public short stateMask;
        public char[] pszText;
        public int cchTextMax;
        public int iImage;
        public LPARAM lParam;
        public int iIndent;

        protected List getFieldOrder()
        {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "mask", "iItem", "iSubItem", "state", "stateMask", "pszText", "cchTextMax", "iImage", "lParam", "iIndent" });
        }

    }
```

My structure initialization is as follows:

```
User32.LVITEM lvItem = new User32.LVITEM(); //User32 is the name of the interface containing the LVITEM structure
lvItem.mask = 0x00000001; //code for LVIF_TEXT
lvItem.pszText= new char[260];
lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
lvItem.cchTextMax = 260;
```

I am calling the SendMessage function inside a for loop to print the names of all the list view items as follows:

```
for(int j=0;j<nItems;j++)
{
lvItem.iItem= j;
LRESULT lrs = User32.INSTANCE.SendMessageA(handleToListView, (0x1000 + 45) , new WPARAM(j), new LPARAM(lvItem.getPointer().getLong(0)));
}
```

If I print lvItem.getPointer().getLong(0) - I get 0, instead of a long value which represents the pointer.

If I print lrs or lvItem.pszText - I dont get the name of the folder. I get a blank value / 0.

I know that the JNA documentation says that a pointer to a structure is treated as a structure in JNA. But if I dont do lvItem.getPointer, then how will I be able to convert the structure to a long value which is required as an argument to the LPARAM constructor?

What am I doing wrong? Please help. I have already spent alot of time researching and since I am new to JNA, havent been able to understand what is going wrong.

Environment: Win XP Pro,
JNA version : 3.4

Answer (score 1):

If you use a primitive array within a `Structure`, JNA interprets it as a primitive array nested within the native `struct`.  The `LVITEM` field `pszText` has pointer type, and more specifically represents a writable byte buffer, so you must use `Memory` (or an NIO buffer).  Using `String` is only appropriate for native `const char *` (i.e. where the buffer is read-only).  After the call, you can use `Pointer.getString(0)` to extract the native NUL-terminated string from the memory buffer.

As for "converting" a structure into an `LPARAM` value, there's no need.  You are free to define your own method signature for `SendMessage` where the fourth parameter is of type `LVITEM` (i.e. a native `struct *`).

I'd also recommend using the `W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS` when initializing your `User32` library; they automatically handle mapping `String` and `SendMessage` to the appropriate native API mappings (windows ANSI or UNICODE, defaulting to UNICODE) so you can use `String` instead of `WString` and `SendMessage` instead of `SendMessageW`.

**EDIT**

For allocating the buffer to which the called function will write:

```
public static class LVITEM extends Structure
{
    ...
    private static final int MEMSIZE = 260;
    public Pointer pszText = new Memory(MEMSIZE);
    public int cchTextMax = MEMSIZE;
```

The above structure (LVITEM) should return 60 for its size (more if you're on 64-bit).

Comment: Hi technomage, thank you for your reply. But I have a question. How would I define my own method signature for SendMessage where the fourth parameter is of type LVITEM?
When I put : 
LRESULT SendMessageA(HWND hWnd, int Msg, WPARAM wParam, LVITEM lvItem); in the interface for User32 and, 
LRESULT lrs = User32.INSTANCE.SendMessageA(handleToListView, (0x1000 + 45) , new WPARAM(j), lvItem);
my program simply crashes on running.

Comment: Also, do I need to allocate the memory to the Structure by explicitly issuing some allocateMemory type command?

Comment: Your program crashes because your `LVITEM` fields aren't the right size.  UINT will be 4 bytes, not two, and pszText must be of pointer type.

Comment: Structures auto-allocate their own memory unless you explicitly pass a `Pointer` to the ctor.

Comment: I have tried to follow your advice and here is what I did!
I declared pszText in the structure LVItem as a Pointer - public Pointer pszText; 
The constructor for LVItem now looks like this: public LVITEM() { Memory m = new Memory(260); pszText = m.getPointer(0); cchTextMax = 260; }

The call to sendmessage is now like this: 
LRESULT lrs = User32.INSTANCE.SendMessageA(handleToListView, (0x1000 + 45), new WPARAM(1), lvItem);

I am them doing this: lvItem.read();

Comment: And I am then trying to print out the result in 2 ways: System.out.println(lvItem.pszText.getString(0)); System.out.println(Native.toString(lvItem.pszText.getByteArray(0, 259)));The program does not crash now, but I get a junk character printed as a result: 0Põ

Comment: Please help me with a snippet of code to show me exactly what Im doing wrong. I know I am close to the resolution with your help, but I somehow not able to get right.

Comment: Is there a problem with the way I am calling SendMessage or is there a problem with the way I am attempting to initialize pszText? As per MSDN, pszText is a pointer to a null terminated string. So I created an object of Memory above which should allocate 260 bytes of memory. And then obtained a pointer to that memory location and then assigned pszText that pointer - is this wrong?

Comment: Assign the `Memory` directly to the `pszText` field, rather than using `m.getPointer(0)`.  The latter assigns a temporary C string representation, which memory is discarded after the function call.  Since the function you're calling is populating the memory, you should call `pszText.getString(0)` *after* the function call to extract the result.

Comment: I did exactly as you said and it still doesnt work! The program appears to crash and close the open explorer window at the function call and I dont even get to the print statment after that. The constructor for the strcuture is now: `public LVITEM() { Memory m = new Memory(260); pszText = m; cchTextMax = 260; }` Function Call : `LRESULT lrs = User32.INSTANCE.SendMessageA(listView, (0x1000 + 45) , new WPARAM(1), lvItem);` //PROGRAM CRASHES HERE!

Comment: I think the issue is now no longer with the pszText but with my function call. The declaration for SendMessage in my interface is this :`LRESULT SendMessageA(HWND hWnd, int Msg, WPARAM wParam, LVITEM lParam);`
Is this correct or do I need to change something here?

Comment: I saw some examples online which use Structure.ByReference (i.e. in the definition of the structure, they make their strcuture implement Structure.ByReference). I am not doing that at the moment. Do I need to use that?

Comment: You only need `Structure.ByReference` if the native code calls for `struct*` as a structure field.

Comment: Add the stack trace/log of the crash to your original question.