# Retrieving item text with JNA and SendMessage()

Tags: jna, sendmessage

I am attempting to retrieve the item text from a Win32 ListView-like control. I am using JNA and SendMessageW() to send LVM_GETITEMTEXTW to the control. I have been successful at retrieving the item count (via LVM_GETITEMCOUNT) but am stumped at this point. My User32 class is setup like so:

```
public interface MyUser32 extends User32 {

    MyUser32 INSTANCE = (MyUser32)Native.loadLibrary("user32", MyUser32.class);
    LRESULT SendMessageW(HWND hWnd, int msg, WPARAM wParam, LVITEM lParam); 

}
```

My LVITEM class is setup like so:

```
public class LVITEM extends Structure{


    public LVITEM() {
        pszText = new Memory(MEMSIZE);
        cchTextMax = MEMSIZE;
    }

    private static final int MEMSIZE = 256;

    public UINT mask;
    public int iItem;
    public int iSubItem;
    public UINT state;
    public UINT stateMask;
    public Pointer pszText;
    public int cchTextMax;
    public int iImage;
    public LPARAM lParam;
    public int iIndent;

    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {    
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "mask", "iItem", "iSubItem", "state", "stateMask", "pszText", "cchTextMax", "iImage", "lParam", "iIndent"});    
    }
}
```

And the code that calls it all is like so:

```
MyUser32 u32 = MyUser32.INSTANCE;   
LVITEM lvItem = new LVITEM();
WPARAM wPar = new WPARAM(1);

...

lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
res = u32.SendMessageW(handle, LVM_GETITEMTEXTW, wPar, lvItem);

System.out.println(res.intValue());
s = lvItem.pszText.getString(0);        
System.out.println(s);
```

I've left out a bit of the code but I believe those are the important parts. My issue is that when I print out res.intValue() it is always 0 (meaning no text was returned) and when I print out the string value of pszText it is always some garbage characters. I'm completely stumped at this point so any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing that `LVM_GETITEMTEXTW` means unicode (versus ascii), so at a minimum you need to ask for a wide string from your `lvItem.psxText` memory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that probably solves another problem I would have run into down the line. I actually decided to post here based on your comments on another question from Feb: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975347/jna-pass-pointer-to-structure-to-sendmessage-function-of-user32-dll-as-the-lpar?rq=1

I've followed some of the suggestions from that link but nothing I do seems to make a difference.

If it helps I'm also using this MSDN site as reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761055(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You probably need to set the mask to non-zero to indicate which structure fields you want/are valid.

Comment: I've now used Spy++ to look at what is actually being sent to the control and it's garbage so it looks like the issue lies with the LVITEM structure or how it is sent to SendMessageW. The 4th argument to SendMessageW is an LPARAM that is supposed to be a pointer to a LVITEM structure. Am I passing it correctly?

Comment: Does the pointer on the Java side match what is seen by Spy++?  If so, does a memory dump of the Java structure (`jna.dump_memory=true` and call `Structure.toString()`) match *any* part of what is seen by Spy++?

Comment: When I call lvItem.toString() it displays the same memory address as in Spy++. The settings all appear correctly in the Eclipse console but the values are completely different in Spy++.