# Retrieving item text from Win32 ListView using JNA

Tags: java, listview, jna

I’m trying to retrieve item information (text would be enough) from a Win32 ListView control (SysListView32). I’m using JNA’s sendMessage() to send LVM_GETITEMTEXT. SendMessage () takes a pointer to a LVITEM structure which looks like this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
typedef struct {
  UINT   mask;
  int    iItem;
  int    iSubItem;
  UINT   state;
  UINT   stateMask;
  LPTSTR pszText;
  int    cchTextMax;
  int    iImage;
  LPARAM lParam;
#if (_WIN32_IE >= 0x0300)
  int    iIndent;
#endif 
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501)
  int    iGroupId;
  UINT   cColumns;
  UINT   puColumns;
#endif 
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)
  int    piColFmt;
  int    iGroup;
#endif 
} LVITEM, *LPLVITEM;
```

The following is my Java implementation of the LVITEM structure:

```
    public static class LVITEM extends Structure {
        public WinDef.UINT mask;
        public int iItem; 
        public int iSubItem; 
        public WinDef.UINT state; 
        public WinDef.UINT stateMask; 
        public Pointer pszText;
        public int cchTextMax; 
        public int iImage; 
        public WinDef.LPARAM lParam; 
        public int iIndent; 
        public int iGoupId; 
        public WinDef.UINT cColumns; 
        public WinDef.UINT puColumns; 

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[] { 
"mask",  "iItem",  "iSubItem",  "state", "stateMask", "pszText", "cchTextMax",  "iImage", "lParam",  "iIndent", "iGoupId",  "cColumns", "puColumns" });
        }

        //Constructor
        public LVITEM() { 
            Memory m = new Memory(260); 
            mask = new WinDef.UINT((long)1); //code for LVIF_TEXT
            iItem = 0; 
            iSubItem = 0; //no subitem
            pszText = m.getPointer(0); 
            cchTextMax = 260; 
            iImage = 0; 
            lParam = new WinDef.LPARAM(0); 
            iIndent = 0; 
        }
    }
```

The size of the Java structure is 52 bytes which should match the size of the C++ structure.

This is my User32

```
public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
            User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
...
int SendMessage (WinDef.HWND hWnd, int msg, WinDef.WPARAM wparam, LVITEM lvItem);
//Several alternative definitions
//int SendMessage (WinDef.HWND hWnd, int msg, int wparam, Pointer lvItem);
...
}
```

I declare my structure like this:

```
LVITEM lvi = new LVITEM();
lvi.iItem = itemIdx;  // the zero-based index of the ListView item
```

Based on some suggestions from two other posts (see below) I have tried different implementations of SendMessage() with different results. For instance:

```
int ret = user32.SendMessage(hWnd, User32.LVM_GETITEMTEXT, 0,lvi);
```

The program crashes the third party software with the ListView and doesn’t retrieve the text of the item. This is the dump of the structure (setting jna.dump_memory=true):

```
ListView$LVITEM(auto-allocated@0x3173e08 (52 bytes)) {
  WinDef$UINT mask@0=1
  int iItem@4=0
  int iSubItem@8=0
  WinDef$UINT state@c=0
  WinDef$UINT stateMask@10=0
  Pointer pszText@14=native@0x380338
  int cchTextMax@18=104
  int iImage@1c=0
  WinDef$LPARAM lParam@20=0
  int iIndent@24=0
  int iGoupId@28=0
  WinDef$UINT cColumns@2c=0
  WinDef$UINT puColumns@30=0
}
memory dump
[01000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[38033800]
[04010000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
```

and

```
ret= 0
```

which means I didnt get anything back and

```
lvi.pszText.getString(0) =  8 8
```

(weird chain of symbols which don't copy well here).

If for instance I do:

```
int ret = user32.SendMessage(hWnd, User32.LVM_GETITEMTEXT, new WPARAM(0),new LPARAM(lvi.getPointer().getLong(0)));
```

I get:

```
ListView$LVITEM(auto-allocated@0x31733e0 (52 bytes)) {
  WinDef$UINT mask@0=1
  int iItem@4=0
  int iSubItem@8=0
  WinDef$UINT state@c=0
  WinDef$UINT stateMask@10=0
  Pointer pszText@14=native@0x380178
  int cchTextMax@18=104
  int iImage@1c=0
  WinDef$LPARAM lParam@20=0
  int iIndent@24=0
  int iGoupId@28=0
  WinDef$UINT cColumns@2c=0
  WinDef$UINT puColumns@30=0
}
memory dump
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
```

(so the structure is empty?) and

```
ret= 0
```

and

```
lvi.pszText.getString(0) = 05  05  � 8
```

In this case the third party software with the ListView does not crash.

I have been successful retrieving other item information from the ListView control like count (with LVM_GETITEMCOUNT) or selected items (with LVM_GETSELECTEDCOUNT).

I have reviewed a couple of similar threads such as:
[Retrieving item text with JNA and SendMessage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724663/retrieving-item-text-with-jna-and-sendmessage)
and 
[JNA: Pass Pointer to Structure to SendMessage function of User32.dll as the LPARAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975347/jna-pass-pointer-to-structure-to-sendmessage-function-of-user32-dll-as-the-lpar)
and many other posts on the web and implemented many the suggestions, but the problem persists.

Any suggestions to help me resolve this would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work in case anyone is interested (draft version):

```
    PointerByReference lngProcID;
    int lngProcHandle;
    LVITEM lvi;
    int strSize = 255;
    int result = 0;
    IntByReference byteIO = new IntByReference();
    Pointer lngVarPtr1 = null;Pointer lngMemVar1 = null;
    Pointer lngVarPtr2 = null;Pointer lngMemVar2 = null;
    Pointer lviVarPtr = null;Pointer lviVar = null;
    int lngMemLen1; int lngMemLen2;

    lngProcID = new PointerByReference();
    int ThreadId = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, lngProcID);

    lngProcHandle = Kernel32.OpenProcess(Kernel32.PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | Kernel32.PROCESS_VM_WRITE | Kernel32.PROCESS_VM_READ, false, lngProcID.getValue());

    lvi = new LVITEM();
    lngMemLen1 = strSize;
    lngMemLen2 = lvi.size(); 

    lngMemVar2 = Kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(lngProcHandle, 0, lngMemLen2, Kernel32.MEM_RESERVE|Kernel32.MEM_COMMIT, Kernel32.PAGE_READWRITE);        

    lvi.cchTextMax = strSize;
    lvi.iItem = itemIdx;
    lvi.iSubItem = 0;
    lvi.mask = User32.LVIF_TEXT;
    lvi.pszText = lngMemVar1;       

    //result  = Kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(lngProcHandle, lngMemVar1, lngVarPtr1, lngMemLen1, byteswritten1);
    result = Kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(lngProcHandle, lngMemVar2, lvi, lngMemLen2, byteIO);

    result = user32.SendMessage (hWnd, User32.LVM_GETITEM, 0, lngMemVar2);

   lngVarPtr1 = new Memory(strSize + 1);
   result = Kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(lngProcHandle, lngMemVar1, lngVarPtr1, lngMemLen1, byteIO);

    result = Kernel32.VirtualFreeEx (lngProcHandle, lngMemVar1, 0, Kernel32.MEM_RELEASE);
    result = Kernel32.VirtualFreeEx (lngProcHandle, lngMemVar2, 0, Kernel32.MEM_RELEASE);        
    result = Kernel32.CloseHandle(lngProcHandle);

    return lngVarPtr1.getWideString(0);
```

Comment: This code does not run. For example `lngMemVar1` is null, causing `ReadProcessMemory` to fail and `Kernel32` methods are called statically, while they are instance methods.